# Distinct number of specific items in list

Tags: mysql

I rarely do stuff in MySQL, so for me this is rocket science ...

I want to know how many times distinct values starting with "abc-" are present in a list.
So for example how many times "abc-table" and "abc-sofa" are present.

The table:

```
| object  
-----------  
| abc-table  
| def-table  
| ghi-chair  
| abc-sofa  
| abc-table
```

The result should be like:

```
| name      number  
-------------------
| abc-table   2  
| abc-sofa    1
```

(Excuse me for the badly formatted tables.)

I tried the following, but that turns out to be incorrect:

```
SELECT object, COUNT(DISTINCT object) WHERE object LIKE abc-% FROM table GROUP BY object
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `WHERE` clause should be after `FROM`.
- Use single quote `'` for the `LIKE` operator.
- No need of `DISTINCT` in your case.

Try the below query:

```
SELECT `object` AS `name`, COUNT(`object`) AS `number`
FROM table 
WHERE `object` LIKE 'abc-%' 
GROUP BY `object`
ORDER BY COUNT(`object`) DESC; -- add order by if you need to sort by count
```

Result:

```
name      number
----------------
abc-table   2
abc-sofa    1
```

<kbd>[`DEMO`](http://rextester.com/NRWG74281)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Use count(*), groupt by ,   like 'abc-%' and having

```
SELECT  object, COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE object LIKE 'abc-%'
group by object 
having count(*) >=1
```

Comment: thanks, but gives an error in the line with "having"